# How to differentiate between image and link http JavaScript

Tags: javascript, contextmenu, getelementsbytagname

Say I have the following JavaScript codes

```
function img_find() {
    var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    var imgSrcs = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
        imgSrcs.push(imgs[i].src);
    }

    return imgSrcs;
}
```

and

```
function link_find() {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    var linkHrefs = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        linkHrefs .push(links[i].href);
    }

    return linkHrefs;
}
```

I am going to actually use `addEventListerner` to create a custom context menu when a link or image is hold on. My plan is to combine both functions into one but then how do I identify if the http returned is for the link or image? Since not all image source `scr` end with an identifiable image extension.

Comment: Have a look at jQuery: there you can use several selection criteria for event binding. For instance, you could introduce a css selector or a function that checks the src element

Comment: The handler can use `this.tagName` to find out if it's an `a` or `img` element.

Comment: Could you give an example of how you would use `addEventListener()`? You bind it to an element, from which you can identify the type quite easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could return an extra parameter, using an object:

```
return {links: links, type: "img"};
```

You can then use something like this:

```
var links = find();

if(links["type"] === "img")
    console.log("I'm an image!");
else if(links["type"] === "href")
    console.log("I'm a link!");
```

Comment: Use an object, not an array, for something like this.